# VSCode AutoPrefixer extension not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoprefixer

I installed the AutoPrefixer plugin, trying to run it but it doesn't work.

I'm highlighting all of my CSS, then hit command pallet, then hit AutoPrefixer:run.

Nothing happens. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Hello there! Did you manage to solve this issue? I have just bumped into this issue.

Comment: Mine is removing almost all `display: flex;` or flex-related prefixes - Not sure if this is because they are no longer needed - or - because I need to change settings. The https://autoprefixer.github.io/ website is not doing this...

Answer (score 11):

I have the same issue and managed to solve with adding this options in settings.json for the Autoprefixer options:

```
"autoprefixer.options": {
        "browsers": [
            "last 4 versions",
            "ie >= 9",
            "> 5%"
        ]
    }
```

After adding this, select all the css and hit autoprefixer as you do before and should work.
The original answer is from here, hope this solve your problem as mine:
https://github.com/mrmlnc/vscode-autoprefixer/issues/122#issuecomment-629762093